# How to use Date values in charts made with gRaphael?

Tags: django, charts, date, raphael

A little premise:
I'm on a diet and I'm trying to draw a chart of my weight loss.

To do that, I'm using a little django app to store the weight readings, and gRaphael (http://g.raphaeljs.com/) charting library to draw the reports.
You can see the wip here: http://www.totanus.net/weight/

At this time I'm printing dates in the X-axis using 'ymd' format to order them properly, but I'm not quite satisfied (actually I'm not even sure that chart is correct at all...) and I'm wondering if there is a better way to render the dates.

The main questions are:

1. Is there a way to use different
   labels other than '100610' or
   '20100610'?
2. Is there a way to set
   fixed x and y axis labels every
   n-days or n-kg?
3. can you suggest me some best practice in rendering this kind of chart (I'm particularly interested in calculating my overall trend)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Teo

Answer (score 5):

Given an `x` which is a `Date` object, I was able to achieve this using the following steps:

1. Take the lowest `Date` value and cache the value of its `getTime()` method in a variable (`originX`)
2. For each `Date` (`curDate`), convert it to a time offset from `originX`.

   ```
   var timePassed = curDate.getTime() - originX
   ```
3. Plot `x` against `y`.

The above gives you a graph where the labels are milliseconds from UTC time. In order to make it look nice, do as @Alastair suggests.

Here is some sample jQuery code. (Note that you will need to provide a `formatDate()` function in order to render the dates properly)

```
$.each(chart.axis[0].text.items, function(i, label) {
    var old = label.attr("text");
    if(old) {
        var newLabel = formatDate(originX + x);
        if(newLabel) {
            label.attr({ text: newLabel });
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it assists!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this code, but I was looking into the same issue.

If you store the integer representation of the time (ticks since 1/1/1970) as the x-axis values, you can then iterate over the values and convert them to dates.

I got the idea for this from: http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/issues#issue/8

```
var canvas = Raphael("holder")
graph = canvas.g.linechart(....)

$.each(this.graph.axis[0].text.items, function (index,label) {
    originalText = label.attr('text'); 
    newText = /* some transformation to originalText */
    label.attr({'text': newText});
});
```

Where your newText is a conversion from the original text value (which is your time in ticks) to a date string.

As I said, I haven't tested this code, but the idea is sound in theory.

Answer (score 1):

See also: the second part of http://weblog.bocoup.com/alternate-x-axis-intervals-in-g-raphael-js-linechart. It's the same as Alastair's solution, but sometimes it helps to have the same thing explained in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

I am a noob, this is what I found from code.

`graph.axis[0].text.items[0].attr({'text': "Jan 3 2010"}) ;`